# socket c-sharp send data without close and shutdown like BufferedWriter.flush in java

Tags: android, sockets, closesocket

i can't receive message while not close socket and i use NetworkStream but while socket not closed not send data my code server c#:

```
         newsocket = serversocket.AcceptSocket();
         newsocket.Send(dataSend);

         newsocket.shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);

         c = newsocket.Receive(dataRec);

         message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(dataRec,0,c);

          XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model_Users));

          using( TextReader reader=new StringReader(message))
            {
                 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.Trim()))
                {
                   users = (Model_Users)xml.Deserialize(reader);
                   dataRec = new byte[1024];
                   dataSend = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("THIS OK");

                   newsocket.Send(dataSend);
                   newsocket.Close();

                }

       }
```

my client android:

```
socket.connect(socketAddress, 10000);
            bufferWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            bufferWriter.write(getrequest);
            bufferWriter.flush();
            String rvdMsgTxt = "";
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

            while ((rvdMsgTxt = bufferedReader.readLine()).equals("")) {
                stringBuilder.append(rvdMsgTxt);
                bufferedReader.mark(100);
                bufferedReader.reset();
            }

            bufferWriter.write(XMLConvertor.usersSerializeXML("user", "pass"));
            bufferWriter.flush();
```

i tired reading question and not find answer please help me

Comment: `i can't receive message while not close socket ` ???? What do you mean? `i use NetworkStream` ???? Where? Could you start telling how you want server and client to communicate? Who is sending what? And who starts sending/receiving?

Comment: `newsocket.Send(dataSend);` What is send? What is in dataSend? Show us. It looks as if the server right away sends something to the client upon connection established. `bufferWriter.write(getrequest);` What is written? What is in getRequiest. Here it looks as if the client directly writes something to the server upon connection established. That is not a good protocoll.

Comment: i can't send and receive a message through c sharp socket without closing it

Comment: data send is byte[] and bufferwritter write a request example : "login" and "list" and server send a response ' 
                switch(message)
                {
                    case "list-menu":
                        sendListMenu();
                        break;
                  .
                  .
                  .